# Get List of Namespaces available in Project in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have ASP.NET Application:
I have added 5 classes with different Namespacess in App_Code folder..

In Default.aspx.cs file.. I just want to get the list of available Namespaces in App_Code folder:

I tried :

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

but i didn't find Namespace that is available in App_Code Folder

How can i find it??

Thanks

Comment: Why didn't you accept this answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the namespaces of an assembly from the types it contains:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetNamespaces(Assembly assembly)
{
    return assembly.GetTypes().Select(type => type.Namespace).Distinct();
}
```

Assembly does not contain a hierarchy to the types, but when accessing a type the namespace can be found using the [Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.namespace.aspx) property.